# Logstash Unable to find JRuby

Tags: ruby, logstash

I download logstash 2.0.0 from [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash).
test output:

```
D:\logstash\bin>logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
Unable to find JRuby.
If you are a user, this is a bug.
If you are a developer, please run 'rake bootstrap'. Running 'rake' requires the 'ruby' program be available.
```

windows also alert me “how to open `.rb`", I have ruby installed, but not familiar with it.

Because it says "If you are a user, this is a bug.", so I think I don't need to install JRuby. Google also do not tell me how to fix this bug.

How do I solve this?

===============================

`setup.bat` same error:

```
D:\logstash\bin>setup.bat
Unable to find JRuby.
If you are a user, this is a bug.
If you are a developer, please run 'rake bootstrap'. Running 'rake' requires the 'ruby' program be available.
```

**update:**

After I associate `.rb` with `ruby.exe` error change to :

```
D:\logstash\bin>logstash
Unable to find JRuby.
If you are a user, this is a bug.
If you are a developer, please run 'rake bootstrap'. Running 'rake' requires the 'ruby' program be available.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file --
 bundler (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from D:/logstash/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:44:in `setup!'
        from D:/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:47:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have modify setup.bat? you can look the setup.bat about the logstash environment.

Comment: @Ben Lim No, I don't. I run `setup.bat` and get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the sulotion.
**I cloned the repo in github** and try to use it directly , which resulted in this error.

If you cloned the repo you need to first bootstrap your system, by using `rake boostrap`, but this is usually for developers. 
For users is better to grab a packages as the ones provided at https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash

Comment: Which is strange, because logstash does not use installed jRuby but it needs and downloads it as a vendor.

Comment: @Thomas Decaux Need it while building source code I think.

Comment: Yes it needs it, but logstash should use the already installed jruby in my understanding

Answer (score 3):

This still persists in 2.3.4!

This is an issue with the .zip download but not with the tar.gz. The vendor/jruby directory is missing in the former. Grab it from tar.gz download.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried solution like download and extract the zip file instead of .tar.gz one but it did not seem to be working. In my case there is a *space* within my filepath, yes a *SPACE*.

In my case I put the logstash in "D:\Program Files\ElasticSearch\logstash". Notice that the "Program Files" folder contain *SPACE*. I copied the logstash to new folder "ProgramFiles" (without space), so the path is now "D:\ProgramFiles\ElasticSearch\logstash" and start the **setup.bat** or **logstash.bat**. And it works.

***Short Answer***: Make sure that the ***file path*** of your log stash does ***not contain any spaces***.

Answer (score 1):

First time - I unzipped the "kibana" and "logstash" zipped files with "Extract All" option.
I got the above mentioned error.

But when I unzipped those zipped files with **"7zip"**, first, it took less time and second, it worked as expected.

Try Unzipping it with **"7zip"**.

Comment: while Extracting using window zip tool I was facing same problem, But After that I extracted same downloaded file with 7zip extract option; **Problem Resolved**.

Answer (score 0):

Start logstash with Windows powershell. Worked for me

```
.\logstash-7.9.0\bin\logstash -f .\simpleconf.conf
```